# What data does a terraform null_resource store in state?

Tags: ssl, terraform, devops, infrastructure

In short, I am generating a key/cert pair on a local machine in order to keep keys out of terraform state. Will my keys end up in terraform state via the apply_ssl_tls.sh script inside of a null resource?

```
variable "site" {}

module "zone" {
  source = "../../../../shared/terraform/zone.tf"
  site = var.site
}

module "dns" {
  source = "../../../../shared/terraform/dns.tf"
  site = var.site
}

# Keys are generated on the local machine via a script in order to keep keys out of state.
# Will a null_resource keep keys out of state?

resource "null_resource" "ssl-tls" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "../../../../shared/scripts/apply_ssl_tls.sh"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    command = "../../../../shared/scripts/destroy_ssl_tls.sh"
  }

}
```

Comment: Basically your triggers are stored in the state to determine execution, but those are already stored in the state anyway because the triggers reference an attribute.

Comment: As a general rule, you can use `terraform show` after applying your configuration to see what's saved in the state. At minimum it will track all of the resource-specific arguments you set in the configuration (but not Terraform-built-in arguments like `provisioner`), and may track other details decided by the remote system. "null_resource" doesn't really have a "remote system", so there isn't anything else for it to track other than an auto-generated `id` that is meaningless.